# Two MySQL tables with same structure but Android java class can only retrieve data from one of the table

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I had created two mysql tables which are "trymarkers" and "05a1ux". Two tables are created with the same structure. But why the Tab3ReminderActivity.java class can only retrieve data from table "trymarkers" while cannot retrieve data from table "05a1ux"? I'm a beginner of Android Studio. Please help me to solve this problem~

[PHP code to retrieve data from mySQL table "05a1ux"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJyQL.jpg)
[PHP code to retrieve data from mySQL table "trymarkers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Gce.jpg)

The "Tab3ReminderActivity" java class below is the code in android studio to display the map in the fragment.

```
public class Tab3Reminder extends Fragment implements
    OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener{

//Our Map
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private String group_id;
View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(rootView != null){
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if(parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try{
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3reminder, container, false);

        //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_GROUP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //group_id = sharedPreferences1.getString(Config.GROUP_SHARED_PREF, "Not Available");

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // Starting locations retrieve task
        new RetrieveTask().execute();
    }catch (InflateException e){

    }
    return rootView;
}

// Adding marker on the GoogleMaps
private void addMarker(LatLng latlng) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}

// Invoking background thread to store the touched location in Remove MySQL server
private void sendToServer(LatLng latlng) {
    new SaveTask().execute(latlng);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //Initializing our map
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    //Creating a random coordinate
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(1.858642, 103.085846);

    // Setting OnClickEvent listener for the GoogleMap
    /*
    mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
            addMarker(latlng);
            sendToServer(latlng);
        }
    });
    */

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    //Animating the camera
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    //Adding a long click listener to the map
    mGoogleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}



// Background thread to save the location in remove MySQL server
private class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        String lat = Double.toString(params[0].latitude);
        String lng = Double.toString(params[0].longitude);
        String strUrl = "http://192.168.1.7/friend3/location_marker_mysql/save.php";
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(strUrl);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    connection.getOutputStream());

            outputStreamWriter.write("lat=" + lat + "&lng="+lng);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();
            outputStreamWriter.close();

            InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";

            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
            iStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

// Background task to retrieve locations from remote mysql server
private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //String strUrl = "http://192.168.1.7/friend3/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php?group_id=" + group_id;
        String strUrl = "http://192.168.1.7/friend3/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";
        URL url = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            url = new URL(strUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            String line = "";
            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
            iStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        new ParserTask().execute(result);
    }
}

// Background thread to parse the JSON data retrieved from MySQL server
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>>{
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
        MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
        return markersList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
            HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
            addMarker(latlng);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

}

}
```

//MarkerJSONParser.java// java.class to pass data from Mysql database to Android Studio

```
public class MarkerJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        JSONArray jMarkers = null;
        try {
            /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'markers' array */
            jMarkers = jObject.getJSONArray("markers");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /** Invoking getMarkers with the array of json object
         * where each json object represent a marker
         */
        return getMarkers(jMarkers);
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getMarkers(JSONArray jMarkers){
        int markersCount = jMarkers.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> marker = null;

        /** Taking each marker, parses and adds to list object */
        for(int i=0; i<markersCount;i++){
            try {
                /** Call getMarker with marker JSON object to parse the marker */
                marker = getMarker((JSONObject)jMarkers.get(i));
                markersList.add(marker);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return markersList;
    }

    /** Parsing the Marker JSON object */
    private HashMap<String, String> getMarker(JSONObject jMarker){

        HashMap<String, String> marker = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String lat = "-NA-";
        String lng ="-NA-";

        try {

            // Extracting longitude, if available
            if(!jMarker.isNull("lng")){
                lng = jMarker.getString("lng");
            }


            // Extracting latitude, if available
            if(!jMarker.isNull("lat")){
                lat = jMarker.getString("lat");
            }

            // Extracting longitude, if available
            if(!jMarker.isNull("lng")){
                lng = jMarker.getString("lng");
            }

            marker.put("lat", lat);
            marker.put("lng", lng);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return marker;
    }
```

}

Comment: in your php side, when you `echo json_encode($markers);` do you got the same response ?

Comment: If using the php code for retrieving data from table "trymarkers", I can see the markers mark on the google map based on the latitude and longitude inside the table "trymarkers". However, I cannot see any markers on the google map when using the php code for retrieving data from table "05a1ux".

Comment: i mean try to access the php script and check, if in the both cases , the data been retrived or not

Comment: I already checked the two php script. But result still the same. Actually two php script are the same, I just change the name of the table at the command "SELECT ... FROM ...". I didn't change any other code inside the php script.